# CSS selector for last <dd> after <dt> or other <dd>

Tags: html, css

I want to style the last `<dd>` after each corresponding `<dt>` without changing the DOM. I found no other way than manipulating the DOM by grouping those related `<dt>` and `<dd>` into a `<section>`, `<div>` or something similar.

Is there a CSS-only way to select every last `<dd>` after a `<dt>` without manipulating `<dl>`?

```css
dt {
  font-weight: bold;
}

dd {
  margin-left: 0;
}

dl dd:last-of-type,
dl * dd:last-of-type {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<dl>
  <dt>Headline 1</dt>
  <dd>This should be styled...</dd>

  <dt>Headline 2</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum...</dd>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum...</dd>
  <dd>This should be styled...</dd>

  <dt>Headline 3A</dt>
  <dt>Headline 3B</dt>
  <dd>This should be styled...</dd>

  <dt>Headline 4A</dt>
  <dt>Headline 4B</dt>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum...</dd>
  <dd>Lorem ipsum...</dd>
  <dd>This should be styled...</dd>

  <section>
    <dt>WORKAROUND: Headline 5A</dt>
    <dt>WORKAROUND: Headline 5B</dt>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum...</dd>
    <dd>Lorem ipsum...</dd>
    <dd>This should be styled...</dd>
  </section>

  <dt>Headline 6</dt>
  <dd>This should be styled...</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: you only need margin to be added?

Comment: My suggestion: add a class to those elements that should be styled.

Comment: @TemaniAfif And `color: red`, at least from the CSS posted...

Comment: @HereticMonkey yes but I was wondering if the color isn't mandatory we can probably find a workaround for the margin since we can also apply it as margin-top for the next element.

Comment: It was a general question about how to select those elements. But you are right - at the moment I just want to add some spacing - and well that could be achieved by setting the margins the other way round - so we could set a top-margin on every dt and overwrite that for every direct following dt ("dt + dt") with margin-top 0.
Nice solution thx @HereticMonkey nice out of the box thinking :)